# Friendship Website SQL Table Design for non mandatory fields in table

Tags: sql, database

**Im building a friendship website. I have a question table that is populated when a user creates an account.**

Each question is has a drop down menu.

The issue im having is there are questions that are not mandatory for the user to answer.

**Mandatory Questions Example:**

What is your favorite color?

**Non Manditory Questions Example**

What is your religion?

**Which method is correct for storing non mandatory questions in this scenario. The user Question table is going to be huge,which method is better considering performance here when i left join these three tables.**

***Method 1***

Store a prefer not to say for questions  that are non mandatory and have not be answered by the user on initial sign up.

**User Table**

```
 userID | username
 1      | jake
```

**User Question Table**

```
 id | userid | question
 1  | 1 | 1
 1  | 1 | 5
```

**Questions Table**

```
id | Question                     | Answer 
1  | What is your favorite color  | green
2  | What is your favorite color  | blue
3  | What is the users religion   | Christian
4  | What is the users religion   | Jewish
5  | What is the users religion   | Prefer not to answer
```

**OR**

***Method 2***

Dont store any value since the user did not answer the question on initial sign up form.

**User Table**

```
 userID | username
 1      | jake
```

**User Question Table**

```
 id | userid | question
 1  | 1 | 1

id | Question                     | Answer 
1  | What is your favorite color  | green
2  | What is your favorite color  | blue
3  | What is the users religion   | Christian
4  | What is the users religion   | Jewish
```

Comment: For a start, don't repeat the questions. If one question can have multiple answers, there is a one-to-many relationship which means two tables in a parent-child relationship.

Comment: Yes I was going to break up the questions into a separate table. For simplicity of the example i displayed it like this.

Answer (score 1):

Either way would be acceptable. There are small advantages and disadvantages either way, so it boils down to what meets your needs, and how you want the user to interact with your application. Here are issues I could think of:

```
Store them: 
+ You know what the user saw/answered (the exact "default" value).
- Takes up extra space in the database.
- Some queries may need to filter out non-answers.

Don't store them:
+ Saves space in the database
- You can't be sure if the user was asked the question or not (particularly if questions change over time).
- Some queries are harder because of "missing" answers.
- Your code has to deliberately not store "default" (non-)answers.
```

On balance, I'd store them.